# Liferay - This site is inactive. Please contact the administrator

Tags: tomcat, liferay, portal, liferay-6

Hi I am testing Liferay Portal however I can no longer access the Portal - when I now access the Portal I get the following message

```
This site is inactive. Please contact the administrator.
```

I believe what has happened is I have made the site inactive in the control panel however I can no longer access the control panel.

If there are any suggestions how I can get round this to reactivate the site it would be greatly appreciated.

Many thanks

Answer (score 7):

Log on to Liferay database and execute this query.

```
UPDATE group_ SET active = 1 WHERE name = '<name of your site>'
```

Then, restart Liferay.

Comment: Everything was already set to 1 in my case.. Also, had to use GROUP_ & ACTIVE (case sensitive)